# C++ sum of digits of each element in a column

Tags: c++, date, addition, digits

I am new to C++, trying to import dates into a program, adding up digits of day, month, year resp and writing back to txt.

input data

```
  sl.no   name  day month year
   1       Rob   15  05   2019
   2       Tim   12  06   2002
```

Desired output data in txt

```
  sl.no   name     day      month   year
   1       Rob       6         5      3
   2       Tim       3         6      4
```

I have been able to import data from a txt file and also add the digits in day but it does not repeat forward. what am i doing wrong ?

sample code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    ifstream theFile("data.txt");
    int id,day,month,year,daysum=0,monthsum=0, yearsum=0;
    string name;

    while (theFile >> id >> name >> day >> month >> year)
    {
    cout << id << ", "<< name <<", "<< day<<", "<<month <<", "<< year<<","<< endl;
    }

    while (day > 0)
    {
    daysum = daysum + (day % 10);
    day = day / 10;
    cout << daysum << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What output do you get? Which debugger are you using to step through and validate the calculations? Also, are you sure the desired output on the year is correct as written?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2019.. all summation of each element is to be done till we arrive at a single digit. eg : year 2019 = 2+0+1+9= 12, 1+2=3..

Comment: Re the expected years, 2002 => 2+0+0+2 != 3.

Comment: How do digits of 2002 add up to 3 and 2001 add up to 2?

Comment: As for Visual Studio: you have a great IDE with all the bells and whistles! Set a breakpoint in the while loop for calculating the first sum. Step through it and check that the values are right at each point along the way. That will help you narrow down the problem. (Hint: we're not going to do your homework for you, but we'll help with specific problems if you're stuck.)

Comment: apologies.. my mistake in quoting the input.... . I am able to add the digits.. not able to continue doing it on the column despite ++ operator..so was wondering what i was doing wrong.. thanks anyway.

Comment: Given "all summation of each element is to be done till we arrive at a single digit. eg : year 2019 = 2+0+1+9= 12, 1+2=3.",  a simpler approach is simply to read the value (2019) to a variable of integral type (say `v`, of type `int`) and then calculate `v % 9`.     Easy to prove mathematically that is correct (assuming the values are always positive).

Comment: @Peter.. thanks.. will try that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert . but have been in your spot a few months ago.. break down the problem into smaller steps..

My approach..

Pseudo Code:

1. Ditch the header
2. Create a function for adding the digits
3. Read data from file
4. Use a loop to run through each element of the every column and use the function created
5. Store results in a variable
6. Output variable to a new text file

comment if there is a specific area where you are stuck..

Try this to reduce it to single digits.. knit to other parts of your code..

```
   #include <iostream>
  
   using namespace std;
   
   int main()
   {
       
       long long num;
   
       cout << "Enter a number: ";
   
       cin >> num;
   
       int sum = 0;
   
       while (1)
       {
           sum += (num % 10);
   
           num /= 10;
   
           
           if (0 == num)
           {
                
               if (sum > 9)
               {
                   num = sum;
   
                   sum = 0;
               }
               else
               {
                   cout << "Answer: ";
   
                   cout << sum << endl;
   
                   return 0;
               }
           }
       };
   
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Can u help in addition till one digit?

Answer (score 0):

you are reading the file and data wrong,
you need to discard the header (sl.no   name     day      month   year)

and then accumulate the daysum while reading the file progressively one row after the other until the end...